# wxGrid, GridColLabelWindow mouse capture assertion failed

Tags: wxwidgets

I am capturing the mouse for **GridColLabelWindow** but getting an assertion message "*!wxMouseCapture::IsInCaptureStack(this) failed. Recapturing the mouse in the same window?*" for the following code:

```
GetGridColLabelWindow()->Bind(wxEVT_LEFT_DOWN, [this](wxMouseEvent& evt) {
            //GetGridColLabelWindow()->ReleaseMouse();

            if (GetGridColLabelWindow()->HasCapture() == false)
                GetGridColLabelWindow()->CaptureMouse();

            evt.Skip();
            });
```

This *only happens* when I click on the grid label window to change the column width (does NOT happen when clicked on grid col label window to select rows).

As an experiment, if I attempt to release mouse before capturing then following assertion is issued "wxWindowBase::ReleaseMouse(): Releasing mouse in 000xxxx (wxWindow) but it is not captured".

I wonder if this is a bug or if I am missing something (wxWidgets 3.1.4, Windows 10, VS 2019).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you're not supposed to interfere with the built-in mouse handling and the grid windows have their own, relatively complicated logic, dealing with the mouse capture, so it's not really surprising that doing what you do breaks it. I'm not sure what exactly are you trying to do, but try handling wxGrid higher level events to implement it, if possible (one problem here is that the resizing events are still [not generated](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/issues/10754) as of 3.1.6, but it would be nice to add them...).

Comment: I am trying to implement a smoother way of selecting multiple columns. When making a selection at GridColLabelWindow, the mouse has to stay within the boundaries of the window, which is quite inconvenient. My goal was to improve this by capturing the mouse. Despite the assertion message (which only happens when aiming to resize the columns), it works without any problems in release mode.

Comment: By the way, when is the release date for 3.1.6 or better 3.2?

Comment: Found at https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/milestone/11